# how to change the templateUrl of a state upon authentication in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router, state

here i have a neatly configured routing pattern in ui.route

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);

app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('App', {
        url : '/',
        views : {
            'header' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/header.jsp',
                controller : 'headerController'
            },
            'body' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/indexbody.jsp',
                controller : 'indexBodyController'
            },
            'footer' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/footer.jsp'
            }
        }
    }).state('App.Dashboard', {
        url : 'Dashboard',
        views : {
            'body@' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/dashboard.jsp',
                controller : 'dashboardController'
            },
            'dashboardBody@App.Dashboard' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/dashboard_adddeal.jsp'
            }
        }
    }).state('App.Dashboard.AddDeal', {
        url : '/AddDeal',
        views : {
            'dashboardBody@App.Dashboard' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/dashboard_adddeal.jsp'
            }
        }
    }).state('App.Dashboard.Section2', {
        url : '/Section2',
        views : {
            'dashboardBody@App.Dashboard' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/a.html'
            }
        }
    });
} ]);
```

Everything is working fine, but i want to change the "body-view" in 'App' State After the authentication is successful

to simply put it i want to show a different state after authentication.

im new to angular, so go easy on me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be dependent on how you have implemented your authentication, but there are a couple of ways to dynamically specify a template.

`templateUrl` can be a function which takes one parameter,`$stateParams`, and returns a URL

Alternatively, `templateProvider` can be a function with injected parameters that returns template HTML.

Detail here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates

With that said, I would exercise caution with either of these paths.  If the user's authentication status changes without a state change, the template in use may not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resolve` promise on your `$stateProvider.state` call.

Ex:

```
.state('App', {
                url: '/',
                /*some skipped lines*/
                resolve: {
                    /*verify the authentication*/
                    verify();
                    $state.go('App.Dashboard');
                }
            });
```

More details about you can do in here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#resolve